# Business Logic design solutions for constructing a JTree with a fixed number of constants

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treenode

As part of my homework, I've been asked to create a JTree Model with a fixed set of constants (Authors and Books)  Presented below is only a small subset of constants to include.  Is there a more elegant and maintainable solution to build the tree?  I would have preferred to create a database but we have been advised that this is too complex at the moment.  Any design advise or patterns would be much appreciated.

As a side note I couldn't find a homework tag.

```
public class TreeBuilder {
  public static ItemNode build(){
    ItemNode rootNode = new ItemNode("Library", ItemNode.NODE_ROOT);

    ItemNode authorOne = new ItemNode("Author One", ItemNode.NODE_AUTHOR); 
    ItemNode bookOne = new ItemNode("Book One", "isbn12345", ItemNode.NODE_BOOK);
    ItemNode bookTwo = new ItemNode("Book Two", "isbn54321", ItemNode.NODE_BOOK); 

    authorOne.addChild(bookOne);
    authorOne.addChild(bookTwo);

    ItemNode authorTwo = new ItemNode("Author Two", ItemNode.NODE_AUTHOR);
    ItemNode bookThree = new ItemNode("Book Three", "isbn98765", ItemNode.NODE_BOOK);

    authorTwo.addChild(bookThree); 

    rootNode.addChild(authorOne);
    rootNode.addChild(authorTwo); 

    return rootNode;
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it better to define a file (xml or json) to reflect the structure?

Answer (score 0):

[`TreeDemo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TreeDemoProject/src/components/TreeDemo.java), discussed in [*How to Use Trees*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html), is a book-related [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#eg). The `createNodes()` method creates the tree nodes. The first few examples progress in complexity, so you might start with the first.